# Determine if a list of numerical values (samples) is ascending or descending (find slope)

Tags: c#, graph, statistics

I am looking for a way to determine if the data in a list of samples is clearly ascending or descending. The data has incrementing x values and a y value between 0 and 100%.

The Y values can have different behavior, and the count of the data could be between 10 to 200 samples. I need to be able to determine if the Y values ascend or descend clearly and to also detect if they are fluctuating too much or not changing enough.

You can see different examples in the image below.

in 1. the data changes from around 95% to 50% and the slope is clearly negative

in 2. the data fluctuates around 80%, the slope can't be determined so it should ignore it

in 3. the data changes from around 50% to 100% so the slope is clearly positive, there is 1 sample that drops to 0% because of inaccurate reading

in 4. the data changes from 100% to 50% multiple times with two glitched readings that drop to 0%, the slope can't be determined so it should ignore it

in 5. the data changes from around 85% to around 80%, the slope is negative, but the change is very little so it should ignore it

in 6. the data stays stable at 100% and then switches to 50% and stays at it, the slope is negative

It's very easy to do this observations by just looking at the graphs, I want to know if there is an easy way to get to this conclusions easily and programmatically. 
For cases 2 and 5 I can check if the amplitude between min and max and if it's bellow a certain threshold ignore the data, however it there is an inaccurate sample (that drops to 0), the amplitude will look good. I guess I can try to filter sudden spikes, but then how can differentiate between a spike and the sudden drop from 100% to 50% in case 6?

[image]

After some searching I got to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression ,where I can check the slope of the regression line but I have no knowledge in statistics and it's not very good for processing cases like 4.

Here is my C# code, it returns a positive or negative double number or 0 in case of problems. I can then check and ignore data with slope between -0.3 and 0.3 (or some other threshold)

```
private double getSlope(List<DataPoint>points)
    {
        if (points.Count == 0) return 0; 

        double slope = 0;
        double avgX = 0;
        double avgY = 0;
        double avgXY = 0;
        double avgX2 = 0;
        double avgY2 = 0;

        foreach (var p in points)
        {
            //calculate the sums
            avgX += p.X;
            avgY += p.Y;
            avgXY += p.X * p.Y;
            avgX2 += p.X * p.X;
            avgY2 += p.Y * p.Y;
        }
        //calculate the average 
        avgX /= points.Count;
        avgY /= points.Count;
        avgXY /= points.Count;
        avgX2 /= points.Count;
        avgY2 /= points.Count;

        try { slope = (avgXY - avgX * avgY) / Math.Sqrt((avgX2 - avgX * avgX) * (avgY2 - avgY * avgY)); } catch {} 

        return slope;
    }
```

So can you suggest another approach that is better for my situation, I would like an algorithm in pseudo code, a link to a useful resource or just suggestions.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that this is a math problem, not a programming one. I sugest you ask in the math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think it's a math problem, or at least if I present it as a math problem I would probably get a math answer which would be of no use to me.

Comment: Why the math answer would be of no use to you? With the answer you could write the code, or at least ask for help on how to write a code that implement that answer. Another option is this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/#

Comment: I'll follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] array = new int[,]
            {
                {  95,  50 },
                {  77,  78 },
                {  52, 100 },
                { 100,  73 },
                {  86,  77 },
                {  99,  50 }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                float i1 = array[i, 0];
                float i2 = array[i, 1];

                var calc = i2 / i1;

                if ( calc < 0.70 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} negative", calc);
                }
                else if ( calc > 1.3 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} positive", calc);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ignore", calc);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to compare the beginning & last values. My output is exactly as you required - i.e.

```
0.5263158 negative
1.012987 ignore
1.923077 positive
0.73 ignore
0.8953488 ignore
0.5050505 negative
```

Comment: True for the given samples, but in general the first or last point might be an outlier

Comment: This was the first think I tried and it works in most of the cases, However because you are looking at just the two end points, you don't know what has happened to the signal in between. This means that it could easily falsely interpret cases like 4, or if the start or end point happens to be an invalid reading (the ones circled in green) it could result in a wrong result. Imagine if case 3 ended on the invalid reading, it would start at 50% and end at 0% and it would be calculated as a negative slope but in fact the slope for case 3 is positive.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] array = new int[,]
            {
                {  95,  50 },
                {  77,  78 },
                {  52, 100 },
                { 100,  73 },
                {  86,  77 },
                {  99,  50 },
                {  50,   0 }
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                float i1 = array[i, 0];
                float i2 = array[i, 1];

                var calc = i2 / i1;

                if (calc > 0.10 && calc < 0.70)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} negative", calc);
                }
                else if (calc > 1.3 && calc < 2.00)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} positive", calc);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ignore", calc);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I added 'bounds' - if the movement is too far (positive or negative) it will be ignored. You can adjust the tolerance. I added your example of a movement from 50 to 0 & you can see that it is ignored. You could just ignore these large fluctuations & hold on to the existing value.